# Oracle PL/SQL: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EMP_PROJECT'

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Create PLSQL procedure which takes a customer id as a parameter and shows
his/her booking. For each booking show room No, hotel, start date and duration

```
create or replace procedure emp_project(CustID NUMBER)
is 
cursor ecur
is
select r.RoomNo, r.HotelName, StartDate, Duration
from Room r, Booking b
where r.RoomNo=b.RoomNo
and r.RoomNo = b.CustID;
begin
for erec in ecur loop
dbms_output.put_line(erec. RoomNo ||' '||erec. HotelName ||' '|| erec. Duration);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Can someone please explain What's wrong with my parameter?
I get this error when I run it:

```
SQL> exec emp_project
BEGIN emp_project; END;

     *ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EMP_PROJECT'
    ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
    PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Here are my tables if that helps:

http://textdump.net/raw/3315/
http://textdump.net/raw/3316/

Comment: Looks to me like you're not actually providing a parameter.

Comment: I'm trying to read a CustID as an input, is emp_project(CustID NUMBER) the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Your procedure requires a parameter (nothing apparently wrong with that), but your call to it (`exec emp_project...` etc.) doesn't seem to provide one. PL/SQL is not my thing, so I'm not providing an answer - just an observation.

Comment: exec emp_project(1) Worked! You are right, I was expecting a prompt or something, silly me.

Comment: Could you submit that as an answer so I can upvote you? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your procedure requires a parameter (nothing apparently wrong with that), but your call to it (`exec emp_project...` etc.) doesn't seem to provide one.

Try this:

```
exec emp_project(1);     // or any appropriate value instead of 1
```